# Rails 4 multi-domain single-app global instance variable or session var?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a multi domain single-app in Rails4 (which I am very new to) and I am needing some advice. The sites are all the same but have different styling and logo sets. Data all comes from a JSON API and a single DB. So I need some variable to decide which site theme to actually present up front.

On deciding from which domain a browser client reaches the app, I use following before_action which I am calling in my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_site 


   def set_site
     logger.debug "client comes from domain: #{request.domain}"
      if Rails.env.development?         
       session[:site] = case request.domain
          when "domainA.dev" then "A"
          when "domainB.dev" then "B"
          when "domainC.dev" then "C"
          else "default"
        end     
        else session[:site].blank?
            if Rails.env.staging?
          session[:site] = case request.subdomains.last # *.yourstagingdomain.com
            when "domainA" then "A"
            when "domainB" then "B"
            when "domainB" then "C"
            else "default"
          end
        elsif Rails.env.production?
          session[:site] = case request.domain
            when "domainA.com" then "A"
            when "domainB.com" then "B"
            when "domainC.com" then "C"
            else "default"
          end
        else
          session[:site] = "default"
        end
      end
    end
   ...
```

The script is loosly based on an older article from [here](http://commonmedia.com/blog/how-serve-multi-site-rails-apps-and-use-pow-make-it-easy/)

In this case is it better to use a session variable(future plan is to actually share sessions between the similar domains)? Or wrap the site variable in an instance variable using a class?

Further how can I target the asset pipeline, and also i18n yml files to load styles, themes and site specific language differences.

On styles I am currently calling this in the template but for performance will this be ok?

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{session[:site]}", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Thanks for any pointers and help!

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: More Rails knowledge!

Comment: Okay :-). And what was your solution in details? ;-) Maybe you could post your steps as an answer..just the basics so I can get the idea..?